# Git: how to init submodule in just created local git repository

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

If I clone a git repository and the repository has a `.gitmodules` file, then `git submodule init` successfully init submodules and `git submodule update` downloads submodules to local directories. But if I manually download the same project, but without the `.git` directory(because the repository isn't cloned), and the project still has a `.gitmodules` file, I  create a new git repository using the command `git init` and init submodules using the command `git submodules init`, but in this case the command prints nothing, and `git submodule update` does nothing. Why? How can I download submodules in just created local repository?

Comment: How did you clone the repository? What command did you use?

Comment: @DavidLeal, `git clone`, with or without `--recursive` parameter, no matter, `get submodule init` will work. But what if I just download an archive with a project and `.gitmodules` file, why I can't init and update submodules in this case?